# pandas.io.sql.read_sqlでバインド変数を使用する方法

Tags: pandas

pandas.io.sql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM database as a where a.date=date)でdateを変数として使用したいのですが方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

変数は `pandas.read_sql` の引数 `params` に渡すことができます。

詳しくは公式documentを参照してください。
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=read_sql#pandas.read_sql